# All threads get suspended

Tags: android, sockets

I am building an app which will continuously get screenshots of my laptop screen and transfer it to my android app but there is some problem within the while loop, when I put a for loop to a limit then my program runs but as it goes till infinity or I replace it with infinite while loop my code suspends all the threads and app crash dueto memory allocation problem, please suggest me to execute my code infinite times so that there are continuous screenshots displayed.

Thank You.

Here is my code

```
public class ScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView img;
int width,height;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();
    //        while (true)
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
        new GetImg().execute();

}
Bitmap imgscr;
public class GetImg extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        Socket client= null;
        try {
            client = new Socket("192.168.1.5",6767);
        InputStream in=client.getInputStream();
        imgscr=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in), width, height, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imgscr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm)
    {
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't do an infinite loop on main thread. Move your loop out of `onCreate`. Also note you're setting all the images at the same time because you're launching 100 (or infinite) AsyncTasks, which run on background. Is this what you want to do? I would assume you want to take the images one after the other since you're overwriting the same ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

@m0skit0 commented the actual reason of getting the ANR. You're out of your run-time memory when you're creating threads in an infinite loop. I'm pretty confused about your purpose though. I think you need to get the screenshots one after one and if this is the case, you can simply add a listener to the `AsyncTask` and get the callback when the screenshot is downloaded fully.

So if I've understood correctly, you need to declare an `interface` like this.

```
public interface DownloadCompletedListener {
    public void onDownloadComplete(String result);
}
```

Now you need to implement the interface in your `Activity` like this

```
public class ScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DownloadCompletedListener {

  private GetImg getImageTask;
  private Bitmap imageBitmap;

  @Override
  public void onDownloadComplete(String result) {
    if(result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
      // Set the image now
      img.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

      // Start next download here
      getImageTask = new GetImg();
      getImageTask.mListener = this;
      getImageTask.execute();

    } else {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}
```

You need to modify your `AsyncTask` a bit. You need to declare the `DownloadCompletedListener`.

```
public class GetImg extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,Bitmap> {

    private DownloadCompletedListener mListener;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        Socket client= null;
        try {
            client = new Socket("192.168.1.5",6767);
        InputStream in=client.getInputStream();
        imgscr=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in), width, height, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imgscr;
    }

    @Override
    protected String onPostExecute(Bitmap bm)
    {
        imageBitmap = bm;
        mListener.onDownloadComplete("SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

So your `onCreate` function will look like this now

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();

    // Start downloading image here. Remove the loop
    getImageTask = new GetImg();
    getImageTask.mListener = this;
    getImageTask.execute();
}
```